# Setting UILabel Text to a Variable Not Outputting Correctly

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create a quick test system to make an array and display it.  Text is inputted into the text field, and when the button is pressed, the text is added to the array, and the output text is updated.  However, if I want to add the data "Sandwich" to the array, it outputs in the label as 'Optional("Sandwich")'.  I have already tried using the ? and ! to get it out, but nothing seems to work.  Would anyone know how to fix this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataEntryTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var addDataButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var addDataLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dataOutput: UILabel!

var List = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.dataEntryTextField.text = ""
    self.dataOutput.text = ""
    dataOutput.sizeToFit()


    //Add more attributes here

    //Apply to the label
    dataOutput.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(TextField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    dataEntryTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

@IBAction func addData(sender: UIButton) {
    if self.dataEntryTextField.text == "" {}
    else {

        if List == [""] {List[0] = "• \(self.dataEntryTextField.text)"}
        else {List.append("• \(self.dataEntryTextField.text)")}

        self.dataOutput.text = List.joinWithSeparator("             ")
    }

        self.dataEntryTextField.text = ""
        dataEntryTextField.resignFirstResponder()


}
```

Comment: `if List == [""] {List[0] = "• " + (self.dataEntryTextField.text ?? "")}
else {List.append("• " + (self.dataEntryTextField.text ?? ""))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use optional binding to unwrap your optional value. Assume you have an optional text,

```
var text: String? = "Sandwich"
print("\(text)")  // This would print "Optional("Sandwich")"
```

When its unwrapped using optional binding, you will get the actual text provided the value is not nil.

```
if let unwrappedText = text {
    print("\(unwrappedText)") // This will print "Sandwich"
}
```

Refer to this [link](http://www.drewag.me/posts/what-is-an-optional-in-swift) to understand Optionals.

In your code, you will have to unwrap your `self.dataEntryTextField.text` value and append it to list.

Comment: After going through the link, I changed my code to add "\(self.dataEntryField.text!)", and the optional went away, thanks!